# using recursion error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, string, recursion, exception, runtime-error

The Program I am trying to write will count the amount of "A"'s within a given string using recursion. What it should do is count how many times the program recurses itself. The Program compiles correctly but when run I am given this error

```
class hw10
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(f(""))
    System.out.println(f("A"));
    System.out.println(f("B"));
    System.out.println(f("BCA"));
    System.out.println(f("ABC"));
    System.out.println(f("ABACAD"));

}

public static int f(String s)
{

    if(s.length() <= 0)
    {
        if(s.charAt(0) == 'A')
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        if(s.charAt(0) == 'A')
        {
            return 1 + f(s.substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            return f(s.substring(1));
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is the full message
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:702)
        at hw10.f(hw10.java:20)
        at hw10.f(hw10.java:35)
        at hw10.main(hw10.java:7)

Comment: Think about these lines carefully `if(s.length() <= 0) { if(s.charAt(0)`.

Comment: and this call System.out.println(f(""))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recursivity lead to short code
try this :

```
        public static int f(String s) {
          if(s.length() == 0) return 0;
          if(s.charAt(0) == 'A') return (1 + f(s.substring(1)));
          return f(s.substring(1));
    }
```